# Why might Chrome (inside Electron) suddenly redirect to chrome-error://chromewebdata?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, chromium

My electron app is randomly redirecting to `chrome-error://chromewebdata`, and I've no idea why. There's no errors in the console, etc.

When the Electron app first starts, the window opens, and it redirects away from my application to that URL and I see an empty blank white screen. No user interaction is necessary, it just happens when the app starts.

If I open devtools, I can see that `window.location.href` contains `chrome-error://chromewebdata` instead of `http://localhost:9080` (the Electron app runs using a localhost URL).

I tried deleting the local Electron/Chrome data folder at `~/Library/Application Support/my-app-name` and starting over, but no luck.

What are reasons that Chrome (in Electron?) can decide to redirect to `chrome-error://chromewebdata`?

Comment: Does this happen without any user interaction? Where exactly do you see the URL you're referring to?

Comment: @snwflk Yeah, no user interaction, as soon as the electron app loads and the window opens, it redirects to there. I see the URL in `window.location.href` when I check why the window went to an empty white screen. Updated the question to describe these details.

Comment: The error URL indicates an invalid URL. If you navigate to a non-existent website in Chrome, you also get this value for `window.location.href`.
Is there a moment that your app is loaded / displayed correctly? Are you navigating anywhere in your code? Can you navigate to your localhost URL in a browser (i.e. not in Electron)?

Comment: @snwflk I see the background color of my app for a moment, so it at least got to the CSS during parsing while on `localhost:9080`. And if I visit `localhost:9080` in Chrome, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` which makes sense, and indicates that at least some JS code is running in Electron where `require` is defined. If I navigate back to `localhost:9080` with `location.replace`, I see the app background again, then after a short moment it redirects back to `chrome-error://chromewebdata`. Hmmmm...

Comment: @snwflk Do you have sample code that will trigger Chrome/Electron to go to that URL?

Comment: Can you check the output in the Network tab in DevTools? Make sure to check "Preserve log". Try to observe the behavior from the beginning. Maybe there's an indication what's going on.

Comment: @snwflk Interesting, thanks for the hint. I found a "failed" connection. Right before going to that `chrome-error` URL, the network tab shows `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in a tool tip while hovering on the failed URL. But there's no hint why. Then, I pasted the failed URL in chrome, and discovered that it redirects to `localhost:5000` which doesn't exist on my machine. But Chrome shows a helpful message in the middle of the view, and it also keeps `localhost:5000` in the URL bar which makes it obvious, and it does not forward to a `chrome-error` page like is happening in Electron. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason, your code is trying to navigate to an invalid (non-existing) URL, which then results in `window.location.href` being `chrome-error://chromewebdata`.

To reiterate: there is no direct redirection to `chrome-error://chromewebdata`, but instead to a URL that doesn't exist or is not reachable.

Check if your code causes this navigation (possibly a redirect). It is very useful to inspect the Network tab in DevTools, making sure that "Preserve log" is checked. This should give some indication about what exactly is happening.

Comment: what should i do, If i need to handle deep link coming from browser window?

Comment: How to handle dead links in Electron? I think that's a different question, warranting a new SO question.

Comment: I found the way to handle it via [registerFileProtocol](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol#protocolregisterfileprotocolscheme-handler-completion). I will link an answer here later : )

Comment: Life saver. To me it wasn't exactly the same thing but it got me on track. I am sharing my issue in answer

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for me in my **Angular** based Electron project. In my case, the problem is that Angular's Webpack server isn't ready to receive requests when I first launch the project. This is only at startup and simple reload can get around it - any live changes to the Angular code will refresh the page without any issue.

This isn't a problem in production as I switch to loading static files in my releases.

To make this a little less annoying, I added a delay to my electron startup:

```json
"start": "concurrently -k \"ng serve\" \"npm run delay && nodemon\"",
"delay": "node -e \"setTimeout(() => true, 3000)\"",
```

Where:

- [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) runs Electron and Angular/Webpack at the same time for faster development.
- [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) watches my electron files and restarts the app when I save changes
- **delay** just uses node to delay nodemon's first startup (works on all operating systems...)

And just for clarity, my `nodemon.json`:

```json
{
    "watch": ["nucleus"],
    "ext": "*",
    "exec": "tsc -p nucleus/tsconfig.json && electron ."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

view-vhcl-cntr-ctgrs.tpl

i replace this file name like below.

view-vhclcntr-ctgrs.tpl

and it worked....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To me it was `launchPath` issue. As I had multiple electron apps in my workspace ([NX](https://nx.dev/)).
So all I needed to do is to set correct url to launch electron.
It was 4200 by default so I updated it to 4202 b/c I already had 4200 & 4201.

```
let launchPath;
  if (serve) {
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
      electron: require(`${__dirname}/../../../node_modules/electron`),
    });
    launchPath = 'http://localhost:4202';
    win.loadURL(launchPath);
  } else {
    launchPath = url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
    });
    win.loadURL(launchPath);
  }

  console.log('launched electron with:', launchPath);
```