# Unable to send email with PDF attachment using Chrome

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I have a form that a user enters information and has the option to upload a document. Once they have filled out the form and click on the submit button, an email is sent to the indicated reciever. This works fine in IE and Firefox (whether the user uploads/doesnt upload a document).

However, when a user uploads a document and submits the form in chrome, it appears that chrome tries to process the document and then crashes.

Here is the logic where I check if a user has upload a document to the form and I store it in a temp folder:

```
<cfif isdefined("FORM.file_type_attachment") AND Len(FORM.file_type_attachment) GT 0>
   <!--- first actually upload the file --->
   <cffile action="upload"
             filefield="file_type_attachment"
             destination="destination of file"
             nameconflict="Makeunique">
    <!--- now create a temporary holder for the attachment later on --->
    <cfset attachment_local_file_1 = "file location">
</cfif>

<!--- Attaches attachment to email. --->
<cfsilent>
    <!--- Note that I used the <CFSILENT> tag, this will kill the white space in this area so your email is not cluttered with white space. --->
    <cfif isdefined("FORM.file_type_attachment") AND Len(FORM.file_type_attachment) GT 0>
        <cfmailparam file="#attachment_local_file_1#">
    </cfif>
</cfsilent>
```

**Update5:** I am able to send certain files with no issues. However, when a user attempts to email a pdf file, Chrome is not able to process and an error populates notifying the user an error has occured. On the dev tools, I am seeing the following:
[image: This is what I have done so far. This works fine if a]

The following code is the approach I attempted to allow users to attach document. Is there a different approach when handling PDF's? Any help would be appreciated.

```
        var sendForm = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = 'MarcomRequestSent.cfm';
            document.getElementById('smbt').disabled = true;
            var form = event.target;
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', undefined);
            xhr.onload = function(e) { 
                if(xhr.status == 200) {
                    //open the modal once the form passes validation
                    var m = modal.open({content: "<div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><h4 class='modal-title' style='color: #9EC630 !important; font-size:28px; text-align:center;'>Request Sent</h4><button style='border:none;' id='closex' type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true' style='color:black'>x</span></button></div><br /><div class='modal-body'>" + "<p style='font-size:16px'>To return to the Marketing page, please click <a href='marketing.cfm'>here</a>."});             
                    if(m == true) {
                        return m;
                    } 
                    console.log('Form data (including any attachment) has been uploaded successfully.'); 
                }
                else {
                    if(xhr.status == 500){
                        alert("We seem to have encountered a problem. Please contact IT.");
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = function(e) { 
                alert("We seem to have encountered a problem. Please contact IT."); 
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
        };

        document.getElementById('marcom_request_form').addEventListener('submit', sendForm);
```

Is there a way I can have users send pdf? Need the help

Comment: Does the file actually get uploaded to the server?

Comment: @DanBracuk: yes.  I have no issues if I am on IE or Firefox. It send the email to the user with an attachment. In chrome, it crashes

Comment: @DanBracuk: Do you have any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Does the file get uploaded when using Chrome?  When it "crashes" do you mean the Chrome browser or on the ColdFusion server?  Open the dev tools for Chrome and then load and submit the form.  Do you see errors in the console?  Check your server logs for errors too.

Comment: @Miguel-F I mean the Chrome browser crashes and not the ColdFusion server. I see no errors populating on the dev tools for Chrome when the form is loaded and submitted. On the dev tool, i see it gets directed to chrome-error://chromewebdata page

Comment: @Miguel-F: would I need to use expandPath (or something similar) on `<cfset attachment_local_file_1 = "file location">`

Comment: It does not make sense to me that Chrome is behaving differently than the other browsers.  You need to find out why using the dev tools (since you are seeing the issue from the browser).  See if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/55716793/1636917

Comment: @Miguel-F: Based on link you provided, I am doing a redirect to a different page notifying the user that their request has been sent, etc. When redirected, an email is sent as well. I do have the dev tool open when testing the form on Chrome and there are no issues besides the chrome-error. I also have the perserve log checked when testing the form and it does not provide any further detail besides showing it goes to the chrome-error page.

Comment: It's good that you got the page to work.  If you want to investigate further, I suggest something like this.  1 - run a coldfusion page that outputs simple text.  2 - run a page with a cfmail tag that does not add attachments.  3 - repeat step 2, but attach a file that is already on the server.  4 - something like you have now, but with no if/else logic.  5 - what you have now.  This will help you see why things broke and prevent recurrence.

Comment: @DanBracuk: I was not able to get the page to work. What I meant with my comment is that the link that Miguel-F provided, I am using the same approach of redirecting the user to another page where they are notified that their email is sent. This approach does not work in Chrome. However, this approach does work in IE and Firefox.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Do I need to first download the document that was upload to the form first (to a temp folder) before sending the email. Once the document is stored in the temp folder, then email the form?

Comment: @DanBracuk: I am attempting to use the xmlhttprequest to send an attachment but the FormData is not sending teh data as it did when I do params var. What am I missing

Comment: You aren't, by chance, using one of the ports that Chrome blocks? https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/main/net/base/port_util.cc

Comment: @Shawn: Yes, I am using Port 25. I am able to send excel, word, txt and image files with no issues. However, when I attempt to send an email with a PDF attachment, that is where I am getting issues

Comment: @Shawn: Would there be a reason why a pdf file would cause issue for chrome not to send the email?

Comment: @DanBracuk: I have deleted the previous question and updated this one to focus on what the issue I am encountering.

Comment: @RobertoFlores  Different browsers might block different things for various reasons. I believe the latest Chrome update added blocking port 10080, or something like that. And it may have added other things. I'm not sure. A normal PDF should be valid, but it may be getting blocked somewhere else, like a virus scanner. Check your server logs and see if there are any messages relating to the failed request.